# Can't sign in to app engine using command line tool or app launcher

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm getting this weird error and losing my mind over it.

I've had my google account for years with the same email and password, and I use it normally daily.I am able to sign in to the app engine dashboard and create apps, but when I try to deploy it using either app launcher or the command line tool and it asks for my credentials it just say that my credentials are incorrect. I've tried a million times and it didn't work, so I changed my password to a new one and it still didn't work.

Has anybody been through it ? Am I being really stupid and missing some detail ?

Thanls in advance for all the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer, pretty stupid as I thought.

You have to go to your google account settings and enable the less secure apps access. You can use this link:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps